# Does ArcMap 10.2.1 no longer listen for DELETE key?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing

We've noticed that in ArcMap 9.3 we could select a feature on the map (while editing of course) and just press the delete key on the keyboard to delete the feature.  ArcMap 10.2.1 does nothing when you press delete.  If we click the delete button (the X button on the toolbar) it will delete just fine.  Did ESRI take away the keyboard event listener?  Is there an option we aren't seeing?

Comment: No, pressing the delete button works when in an edit session (10.2.1).

Comment: Could it be that you have "unfocused" the map by clicking somewhere else in ArcMap (such as Catalog window).? Do you press a del button on the keypad - numlock activated? I am also able to use the Delete button on the keyboard to delete a feature.

Comment: I have noticed it sometimes works and sometimes does not for me, I have yet to determine what is making the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally decided to track this down. *The answer is that the Delete Key does not work in layout view when it editing mode to delete selected features.* Switch back to data view and it will work. The @papadoo answer only applies to data view. in Layout view you can open the attribute table and select the blue X but you cannot just hit delete.

Comment: I would add that I don't think you should be doing editing in layout view? Is there a specific use case for that?

Comment: You can only delete graphics and elements in a layout view, editing/deleting of features should be only done in data view.

Comment: Yep I agree with all comments but this is how to replicate the user issue. X button still works just not delete key.

Answer (score 3):

Per the ArcGIS help pages [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000016000000), you should still be able to delete selected features while in editing mode.

You can either use the Delete key or CTRL + D in Show All Records mode.

Comment: That is what it says but it does not consistently work. Many have noticed this including myself. Sometime I can just hit delete and and other times I need to go to the table and hit the X.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out. If you're selecting items in more than one layer, it won't let you hit the delete button on your keyboard. Turn off the extra layers. In my case, I had a box around the area I was working on to mark my borders. Once I turned it off, I was only selecting items from one layer and could use the delete button on my keyboard again.